# URLencoding in HTTP request for space

Tags: html, http, url

Why is the space character URL encoded to %20? 
I don't see a reason why space is considered to be a reserved character.

Comment: This comment is not constructive in any way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because space is used as a separator in a lot of cases (program with arguments, HTTP commands, etc), so it often has to be escaped, with a \ in unix command line, with surroundings " in a windows command line, with %20 in URLs, etc.

in HTTP protocol, when you try to reach `http://www.foo.com`, your browser opens a connection to the server www.foo.com on port 80, and send the commands:

```
GET http://www.foo.com HTTP/1.0    
Accept : text/html
```

The syntax is "METHOD URL HTTPVERSION"

If you tried to request `http://www.foo.com/my page.html` instead of `http://www.foo.com/my%20page.html`, the server would think "page.html" is the HTTPVersion you're looking for...

Comment: In the dawn of the internet, one defined (restrictively) defined the _allowed_ characters, URLS were simple and adding space in many cases implied a cumbersome quoting. _Think how to let an URL end with a space. ;)_

Comment: When does the resolution from domain name to IP address happen? The browser does this before sending the GET request or does the browser resolve the domain name to IP address before sending the GET request?

Comment: the browser has to open the connection before sending the GET, so it resolve the domaine name, connect to the server by its IP, and send the GET command... (more or less ^^)

Answer (score 2):

See [RFC 3986 Section 2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.3):

```
2.3.  Unreserved Characters

   Characters that are allowed in a URI but do not have a reserved
   purpose are called unreserved.  These include uppercase and lowercase
   letters, decimal digits, hyphen, period, underscore, and tilde.

      unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the [Request-Line](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5.1) of an HTTP request is defined as:

```
Method (Space) Request-URI (Space) HTTP-Version CRLF
```

Naive HTTP servers that stricly adhere to the spec will do something like this:

```
splitInput = requestLine.Split(' ')

method = splitInput[0]
requestUri = splitInput[1]
httpVersion = splitInput[2]
```

That will break if you'd allow spaces in an URL.

Comment: To be fair, that may be a chicken and egg problem. Does the HTTP protocol look the way it does because the URL syntax allows it, or were URLs modeled to not break the HTTP syntax? The HTTP syntax *could* be different... :)